# Find all integer sets $a,b$ where $\gcd(a^2+a+1,b^2+b+1)=3$

Tags: number-theory

How does one find all integer sets $a,b$ where $gcd(a^2+a+1,b^2+b+1)=3$?

It appears that for $gcd(a^2+a+1,b^2+b+1)=3$ to be true, then $a\equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Also, if $(a^2-a+1,b^2+b+1)=1$, it is also possible to say that $gcd(a^4+a^2+1,b^2+b+1)=3$ as well.

However, I was not able to proceed from here. I conjectured that there are infinite such $a,b$ with $a,b>1$, but was not able to prove this.

Currently, integer sets that satisfy the given conditions appear to be $(1,3k+1),(4,7),(16,7)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint** $3|(a^2-b^2 + a-b)$, i.e. $3|(a-b)(a+b+1)$, so either $a = b \pmod 3$ or $a + b = 2 \pmod 3$

Comment: You are correct that you must have $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  Now the challenge is to have $\frac 13(a^2+a+1)$ and $\frac 13(b^2+b+1)$ coprime so the $\gcd$ doesn't get higher.

Comment: @RossMillikan And how does one do that?

Comment: I don't think it is easy.  Multiples of $7$ recur at $4,16,25,37,46 \dots$, alternating gaps of $12$ and $9$.  You never have multiples of $11,17,19,23$.  Multiples of $13$ recur as well

Comment: Are you trying to prove the conjecture (relatively easy), or find all solutions (relatively difficult)?